# Point-line incidence bounds over positive characteristic fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, incidence-geometry

I am aware of work on point-line incidence bounds over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and finite fields, in particular various versions of the Szemeredi-Trotter bounds. I would like to know if work along these lines has been done over function fields like $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. I looked around some and asked some people, but I didn't find anything.

What I'm actually really interested in is arbitrary fields. Results on $\mathbb{C}$ often generalize to arbitrary characteristic zero fields, and results on finite fields imply results on algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$. So that's why I ask about $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

Answer (score 5):

The current best Szemeredi-Trotter bound over finite fields also holds over arbitrary fields. It is in the wonderful paper "[An Improved Point-Line Incidence Bound Over Arbitrary Fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06284)" by Sophie Stevens and Frank de Zeeuw.

Unfortunately, this current best bound of $m^{11/15}n^{11/25}$ is closer to the trivial $m^{3/4}n^{3/4}$ than to the conjectured $m^{2/3}n^{2/3}$.

In a somewhat different direction, model theorists generalize these bounds to things such as o-minimal frameworks and distal. See [Chernikov, Galvin, and Starchenko](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00908)
 and also [Basu and Raz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07362)

Comment: what's known about lower bounds? This should be the much easier direction. I just know the lower bounds in characteristic zero and over finite fields. Is the conjectured bound known to be sharp over an arbitrary field?

Comment: I can describe one reason why I am curious. I can show that certain structures cannot interpret infinite fields. In characteristic zero you just need the lower bounds for Szemeredi-Trotter, in positive characteristic you first reduce to the algebraically closed case and then use the lower bounds over finite fields. The reduction to the algebraically closed case uses a non-trivial theorem. It would be nice to know if I actually need the theorem.

Comment: That I do not know. When the number of points and lines is very large or very small, then this can be done using standard techniques. But I don't recall seeing anything in the middle (and most interesting) range.